# Crystal Reports Formula to parse RTFtext based on font format ie Bold and Italic

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a column of RTF data that looks like the following:

The terms or definitions to be used in this document are:
***Daily Operator.*** Used when the user is.......etc..

Using crystal reports I would like to grab just the BOLD text using a formula or equivalent.

I keep getting the RTF markup instead of standard text. Here is an example that I used to grab first 10 characters.

DIM convertedText as String
convertedText = cstr({table.DefinitionRTF})
FORMULA =  MID(convertedText, 1, 10).

Looking ahead a bit more, how would one determine where the bold or italic Starts. Can you check for crBOLD and return the characters index position?

Thanking all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, Crystal does not have the built-in commands to parse RTF objects by font properties.  The purpose of Crystal Reports is to present formatted reports (and it more or less does this job very well).  **Sorry, but it's definitely not made to be a RTF parser.**

I recommend doing this with some other tool, for example, a VBA script in MS Access that imports the RTF and parses it using the MS Word API.  Probably wouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: Thanks PowerUser. Looks like I will handle it in SQL.

Comment: Just had another thought.  Is the word and definition separated by a particular character sequence, i.e. ": "?.  You can parse your text that way using SQL.